# Marionette driver: not able to perform double click operations in app

Tags: robotframework

I am facing an Issue with Marionette driver..I am not not able to perform double click operations in my application using robot framework.Please suggest how can I proceed further with **double click element** method with Marionette.

Can I write any custom script to make the things work?

Comment: The marionette driver doesn't yet implement the actions for a double click. So either revert to the former driver or simulate the events with a javascript injection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Florent. I am using Robot framework with python so my question is how can simulate with a javascript injection. Please suggest.